# Type of regression for a mix dataset

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, polynomial, fractional-polynomial

I am building a model for the following TYPE of dataset:

Target function has float numerical values

Variables are:

2 variables are float values

4 other variables are integers (Yes/No = 1 or 0)

What type of regression model would you recommend?

I am aware that mixing classification and regular regression in one is not a good idea but I see no other choice since the probability of event is not important but rather its impact (Target function)

Also, most likely it will not be a linear model but rather a polynomial one

Would greatly appreciate all ideas!

CLARIFICATION:

This is somewhat of a mix for factor analysis:

4 variables with 0 or 1 possible values will simply tell if a particular event is present or not. Nothing else

2 variables with continuous values are calculated (independently from the regression) based on additional information.

This is the example of one typical record:

1200 (Target) = Intercept + a1*x1 (=0) + a2*x2 (=1) + a3*x3 (=1) + a4*x4(=0) + a5 * 0.93 + a6*0.26

The number of records will be around 100 to determine 6 coefficients (a1 thru a6) and intercept

I heard something about Shapley Values method used in attribute marketing but not sure if this is the right approach (https://towardsdatascience.com/one-feature-attribution-method-to-supposedly-rule-them-all-shapley-values-f3e04534983d)

Comment: There is not enough information to recommend any type of regression model. The coding of the variables is irrelevant. What is important is how the data were collected and the type of question you hope to answer with them. Can you rephrase the question to focus more on the latter rather than the former?

Comment: Sometimes it is better to take the logarithms of the data and model the data as power functions. There is no general rule as to what one does. However, there is a set method of evaluation for regression modelling. Without knowing what the data types are, one cannot say what should be done.